# Internal Server Error after adding multiple cron jobs

Tags: php, cron

I was adding multiple cron jobs from my cpanel. After about 10 minutes I got an email

```
execl: couldn't exec `/bin/sh'
execl: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

And after that I am continously getting this error:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@********.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
Apache Server at www.******.com Port 80
```

I have already removed all the cron jobs. But still I am getting the error. Please help. Thanx in advance!

Comment: take a look to see what's in the error logs, that will probably give you more of a hint. I'm assuming linux, so probably /var/log/messages /var/log/apache/error_log (could be apache2 or http also)

Comment: I already did. the log mentions this error:[Thu Jul 05 02:50:23 2012] [error] [client 66.249.73.21] SoftException in Application.cpp:574: Could not execute script "/home/thakuria/public_html/index.php"

Comment: I am continously getting the mail from cron daemon as mentioned above